# Turn duplicates into distinct letters in a String

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

We will be given a string s. Suppose for example "creepfe". What we want to do is to remove duplicate and instead add a new letter in that place and new letter must be distinct letter available next to the duplicate letter in alphabetical order. So it goes like this :

creepfe to crefpfe -- first e is distinct and second e is changed to f which is distinct upto that.

crefpfe to crefpge -- second f is changed to g since we already have f before.

crefpge to crefpgf -- since e is already present.

Now again we got f duplicate , so change it to crefpgg , which again got g duplicate so finally we reach "crefpgh" which has all distinct letters.

Started learning java recently and a working code is appreciated ,BUT a good algorithm is what really needed.

Edit : yes capitals do count as duplicates as well. And string length is limited to 10-15 so no worry about running out of distinct letter.

Comment: what about capitals? would that count as duplicate?

Comment: Yes capitals count towards duplicate !

Comment: Seems this is task for sets. Have you tried to use set for chars in string?

Comment: beginner here , had no idea how to proceed apart from brute forcing ( write a function to check a letter is present in string and add next letter if present. And repeat again ) really need a good idea to reduce complexity.

Comment: ^ well, set is used because checking if a letter is already seen before ( contains() ) is an constant O(1) time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution. I m using recursion to left shift the letters if there are duplicates. I also went back and redid my code to include sets as mentioned by MBo. Its not the most efficient, but its a start while you wait for advice from more experienced members of SO

```
public class tester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Application.launch(testclass.class, args);
        String str = "creepFeZZ";

        System.out.println(processStr(str));

    }

    public static String processStr(String str){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HashSet<String> seen = new HashSet<>();

        insertStr(sb, seen, String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)));

        for (int i=1; i<str.length(); i++){
            char currentchar = str.charAt(i);
            char processedchar = goNext(seen, currentchar);
            insertStr(sb, seen, String.valueOf(processedchar));
        }

        //System.out.println(seen.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void insertStr(StringBuilder sb, HashSet seen, String str){
        seen.add(str.toLowerCase());
        sb.append(str);
    }

    private static char goNext(HashSet seen, char c){
        if (c>= 65 && c<=90){
            //if uppercase letter, check if contains lowercase version
            if (seen.contains(String.valueOf((char)(c+32)))){
                c = goNext(seen, (char)(c+1));
            }
            //any left shifting will overflow back to A
            return (char) ((c -(int) 'A') % 26 +(int) 'A');
        }else{
            //if lowercase letter, just check if contains
            if (seen.contains(String.valueOf((char)(c)))){
                c = goNext(seen, (char)(c+1));
            }
            //any left shifting will overflow back to a
            return (char)((c-(int) 'a') % 26 +(int) 'a');
        }
    }
}
```

This gives output of:
`crefpGhZA`

Comment: It's definitely a good start. Sets seem to be good idea to maintain seen elements. I'll be working on this idea since I don't know whether more experienced people will answer this question as it got negative vote. Anyway thanks !

Answer (score -1):

- Find the position where the string contains a duplicate. There are various methods to this. You can Google to find the most efficient one that fits your approach.
- Generate the next character in alphabetical order. The following code shows how this can be done

```
String value = "C";
int charValue = value.charAt(0);
String next = String.valueOf( (char) (charValue + 1));
System.out.println(next);
```

- Repeat the process until there are no more duplicates (have a while loop which breaks when there are no more duplicates)

Comment: The problem is what if the generated characters is already present in the string ? Like in the step  " crefpge to crefpgf -- since e is already present.

Now again we got f duplicate , so change it to crefpgg , which again got g duplicate so finally we reach "crefpgh" which has all distinct letters " . Checking for duplicate again and again and changing again and again seems more complex than I thought. Essentially the problem is directly generating the next alphabet without some check if it is already present in my view .